# AngularJS angular.element current DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was doing some tests with angular.element and wanted to figure out if there is a way to get the current DOM from an hg-click?

Example

```
<div ng-click="angular.element(curElement).parent()..."></div>
```

How do I get the current element? I.e the Div element it belongs to? I don't need to use a directive or a controller, I just want to figure out if there is a way through the above method.

I tried passing in 'this' and '$element' but nothing.

Comment: What happens if you console.log angular.element(this)?

Comment: i don't understand the use case...you don't need a controller or directive? best-practice-wise, you shouldn't really be doing that.

Comment: I have controllers and directives but again, I don't want to get too much into the specifics, just needed a way to do something similar to above. I am aware of the best practices.

Comment: for the console.log, I get a $$childScope object: $$childScopeClass {$$childTail: null, $$childHead: null, $$nextSibling: $$childScopeClass, $$watchers: ...}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `$event` service as parameter

```
 <button ng-click="clickMe($event)">Click Me</button>
```

[**Online Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qvWiknkojs99dwIP5tDa?p=preview)

There are several properties that can help:

`srcElement`, `toElement` or `target`

Comment: Great, this work and I can get the element using target. Do you know if it is possible to execute the 'angular.element' expression within an hg-click directly without being wrapped in a controller function? Just a curiosity.

Comment: Out of curiosity what are they?

Answer (score 1):

If you define a function so that

```
<div ng-click="doStuff($event)"></div>
```

Somewhere in your controller, you can then get a reference to the raw DOM element by using

```
$scope.doStuff = function ($event){
    var el = $event.target;
}
```